# Есть ли стилистичекая ошибка в предложении?

Tags: стилистика, глаголы, род, стилистическая-ошибка

*Продавец магазина одежды в Черновском районе Читы сообщила в полицию о том...*

Корректно ли в данном случае употреблено слово "сообщила"? Нет ли здесь стилистической ошибки, связанной с согласованием по роду?

Answer (score 2):

***Продавец магазина одежды в Черновском районе Читы сообщила в полицию о том...***

1) В этом предложении возможно согласование в женском роде, при этом автор  дополнительно указывает на то, что продавцом была женщина. Для газетного стиля  такое согласование является нормой.

2) Следует отметить, что  подлежащее удалено от сказуемого, поэтому отсутствие формального согласования в роде не так заметно. Сравнить: *продавец сообщила.*

3) Согласование в м.р. делается  **в книжно-письменных стилях** (особенно в **строгой официально-деловой речи**): Диссертант изложил интересные наблюдения. Уже известный читателям автор предложил новую статью.

http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/letters/59-rubric-89

Answer (score 1):

Женщину-продавца называют и ***продавщицей** (более разговорный вариант), и **продавцом** (более деловой стиль).* Глагол, независимо от выбора наименования, сохраняет свою форму ***женского рода.*** Поэтому у Вас ***с согласованием всё правильно.***

Подробнее об этом [здесь](https://www.ekburg.ru/news/18/62423-kak-pravilno-pisatel-ili-pisatelnitsa-petrova/):

> ...в деловой речи существует ряд наименований лиц мужского пола, к которым нет параллельных соответствий женского рода. К ним относятся:
>
> - административные и должностные названия: адвокат, делегат, депутат, консультант, корреспондент, министр, мэр, премьер-министр, помощник (депутата), посол, президент, референт, руководитель, советник, эксперт;
> - обозначения ученых степеней: академик, доктор наук, доцент, кандидат наук, профессор, член-корреспондент;
> - названия лиц по военным специальностям: боец, воин, генерал, капитан, майор, офицер, пилот, полковник, сержант;
> - слова на -ор, -тор, -ер, -вед, -лог, -граф, -фил: автор, библиограф, библиофил, губернатор, директор, лектор, литературовед, оратор, прокурор, редактор, спринтер, филолог, языковед.